# Logic behind selecting even square root for fe_sqrtm1 = sqrt(-1)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet, key-image

That is the logic behind selecting even square root for `fe_sqrtm1 = sqrt(-1)`

```
x = sqrt(-1)

x = 547cdb7fb03e20f4d4b2ff66c2042858d0bce7f952d01b873b11e4d8b5f15f3d
x = 2b8324804fc1df0b2b4d00993dfbd7a72f431806ad2fe478c4ee1b274a0ea0b0
```

Value `2b8324804fc1df0b2b4d00993dfbd7a72f431806ad2fe478c4ee1b274a0ea0b0` is used here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/v0.17.1.9/src/crypto/crypto-ops-data.c#L38

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll find that it's the *positive* (as opposed to "even"), that's chosen (by convention). The *positive* one has the sign-bit set as 0.